# Old 'First Posts' in First Posts Queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, questions, new-users

I just got a bunch of *First Posts* in the review queue from 8 days ago (not audit reviews). Was there a bug that's just been fixed? Is this a bug that wasn't known about before?

Additionally, had these questions not been added to the question list properly?

For example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134092/set-minimum-quantity-and-shipping-fee-base-on-customer-adress-in-magento had 3 views when I reviewed it (10 mins ago), and it's on 14 views as I write this, and it was posted 8 days ago, according to the timestamp.

Perhaps this is a timestamp problem?

Basically, WTF?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Elsemeta, I commented on a [late late review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213020/213963) - there are [similar things that can happen for first posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235034/213963) that would cause a poster's post to *now* be considered a first post review when it wasn't the case when it was posted.

I will point out that the OP of the question you reviewed has an editor badge (with no edits) awarded on Sept 30, with no other activity shown.  This would indicate that the OP had a deleted question that they edited.  When the *first* post was deleted (given the timing on this, I suspect a roomba script), this one now became a first post and thus qualified for the conditions for the review (it hasn't been first post reviewed before, it is the first visible post by the author).

Thus the sequence of events (based on what my non-mod eye can see):

1. Before Sept 30th, a post (lets call it `A`) was made
2. At some point, `A` was reviewed in the first post queue.
3. Sept 30th, `A` was edited
4. October 1st, a post (the one you point out - lets call it `B`) was made
5. October 9th, `A` was deleted as part of a roomba script that ran
6. October 9th, `B` became eligible for first post queue: OP had less than some threshold rep, this is the first visible post
7. [You review `B`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5963361) (I might point out that you might have considered [removing the thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and formatting the data block, fixing the punctuation and spacing and capitalization -  even if it is not a good post, providing guidance for people asking question about what is expected can be helpful... but that's another matter)

Comment: That could well explain this post, and thanks for the explanation. Could this apply to the dozen or so other posts I just reviewed from 8 days ago (ie, the same *suspected* roomba script)?

Comment: The roomba script for closed, no positive score or accepted answer, down voted posts runs [on posts nine days old](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/213963) after last edit to the question.  This matches up about with the timeframe there.  Reviewing right after that script runs may kick many questions from people who had their first post deleted into the first post queue again.